# replace properties in a properties file by using GNU tools

Tags: bash, makefile, gawk

is there an easy way to accomplish ant expandproperties functionality in Makefiles?, an example follows:

Given the three files:

File main.properties

```
principal.name=John
```

File 1.properties

```
name=${principal.name}
```

File 2.xml

```
<properties name="${principal.name}"/>
```

I'm pursuing to replace all appareances of principal.name in files 1.properties and 2.xml with John, i should use GNU tools for i intend to incorporate it in a Makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is doable.  I'm doing it here by using awk to construct a sed script which does the substitution:

```
cat main.properties | awk -F= '{print "s/\\${" $1 "}/" $2 "/g"}' | sed -f - 1.properties
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. As a noteside i had paths in main.properties so first i had to pipe the file to sed and replace path separators with '\/' so that it wouldn't foul the last sed, much appreciated!